# How do I get Thymeleaf to render this section of BlueImp template code?

Tags: thymeleaf, blueimp

I have some x-tmpl code from the BlueImp library to display on a Thymeleaf page.  How can I have Thymeleaf render this?  Unless I'm doing it wrong, it seems that CDATA and `th:inline` doesn't work here.

```
    <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
    <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
            {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
                <tr class="template-upload fade">
                    <td>
                        <span class="preview"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                        <strong class="color--error field--error"></strong>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p class="size">Processing...</p>
                        <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn--success btn--lg start" id="uploadPaystub" name="_eventId_uploadStub" style="padding: 2px;">
                                <span class="btn__text type--uppercase">
                                    Start
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        {% } %}
                        {% if (!i) { %}
                            <button class="btn btn--warning btn--lg type--uppercase cancel">
                                <span class="btn__text">
                                    Cancel
                                </span>
                            </button>
                        {% } %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% } %}
    </script>
```

To paraphrase [this external link](https://nixmash.com/post/spring-mvc-thymeleaf-and-the-blueimp-fileupload-plugin), it seems like one solution was to just use Velocity for the block and use `utext` in Thymeleaf to display it.  Is there a better way than resorting to another library altogether?

Comment: Are there thymeleaf variables in the block of code you pasted?  Or do you just need that code placed in a thymeleaf file?

Comment: Good question. I am just guessing but it seems like the latter because we were using it without any issues as a JSP without any scriptlets.  The `{%` notation is remarkably similar, but it's not a JSP scriptlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, that is a tricky one...  I agree with the original author (it appears impossible to put that javascript template directly in a thymeleaf template).  That being said, you don't need velocity for this case.  I would just put the contents of the javascript in the `src/main/resources/javascript/upload.js` and then add the contents to the model (no need to parse it with velocity -- just read it directly from that file).  I have my own utility, [but it should be easy to get working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255146/):

```
// Controller
model.put("upload", Utilities.resourceToString("javascript/upload.js"));

// Thymeleaf template
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl" th:utext="${upload}" />
```

Comment: even trickier since I'm using Spring Webflow for this page.  Will have to try a few things.

Comment: Our developer worked on this a bit and it turns out that it wasn't loading before due to some missing css classes and wrong references to jQuery objects.  Sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using ajax call to javascript file. After ajax call I encoded the response in order to avoid js execution. After encoding just insert in any element.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? It appears that blueimp templates ignore html comments, and the `<![CDATA[` `]]>` sections allow thymeleaf to ignore the invalid characters.

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<!-- <![CDATA[ -->
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-upload fade">
            <td>
                <span class="preview"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                <strong class="color--error field--error"></strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="size">Processing...</p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--success btn--lg start" id="uploadPaystub" name="_eventId_uploadPaystub" style="padding: 2px;">
                        <span class="btn__text type--uppercase">
                            Start
                        </span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
                {% if (!i) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn--warning btn--lg type--uppercase cancel">
                        <span class="btn__text">
                            Cancel
                        </span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
<!-- ]]> -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-upload fade">
            <td>
                <span class="preview"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
                <strong class="color--error field--error"></strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="size">Processing...</p>
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--success btn--lg start" id="uploadPaystub" name="_eventId_uploadPaystub" style="padding: 2px;">
                        <span class="btn__text type--uppercase">
                            Start
                        </span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
                {% if (!i) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn--warning btn--lg type--uppercase cancel">
                        <span class="btn__text">
                            Cancel
                        </span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: You may consider adding a few comments and explanatory sentences additional to your code as this increases the value of your answer for other users.